# Doesn't work: gradle-5.0-milestone-1-all.zip

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

Already updated:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-milestone-1-all.zip`

however:

```
.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.0-milestone-1-all/6dyq36h9cpyjh4c7hz2nzqfq6/gradle-5.0-milestone-1/bin/gradle
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

[issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/117642383)

Comment: This is my issue too! I joust use gradle commands from terminal :)

Comment: This is the issue that I get when I try to update jetbrains to 5.1-rc-1 : https://gist.github.com/urosjarc/d7bb124229f0dbcef88e80c7e6cfbd43